# What is the oldest hindu temple?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, temple

which temple among the Vaishnava/Shiva shrines are the oldest?

Thanks.

Comment: Avimukta Kshetram, Kuru Kshetram, Prayaga, Arunachala Kshetram etc... can be considered as oldest Tirtha sthalas..